# Can I have a method returning IEnumerator<T> and use it in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I need to set the height of every textbox on my form, some of which are nested within other controls.  I thought I could do something like this:

```
private static IEnumerator<TextBox> FindTextBoxes(Control rootControl)
{
    foreach (Control control in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            // Recursively search for any TextBoxes within each child control
            foreach (TextBox textBox in FindTextBoxes(control))
            {
                yield return textBox;
            }
        }

        TextBox textBox2 = control as TextBox;
        if (textBox2 != null)
        {
            yield return textBox2;
        }
    }
}
```

Using it like this:

```
foreach(TextBox textBox in FindTextBoxes(this))
{
    textBox.Height = height;
}
```

But of course the compiler spits its dummy, because *foreach* expects an **IEnumerable** rather than an **IEnumerator**.

Is there a way to do this without having to create a separate class with a **GetEnumerator()** method?

Comment: Actually, `foreach` doesn’t expect an `IEnumerable` at all (nor an `IEnumerable<T>`). It only expects something that has a `GetEnumerator` method. That method, in turn, need not necessarily return an `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<T>` — it only needs to return something that has a `MoveNext()` method and a `Current` property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the compiler is telling you, you need to change your return type to IEnumerable. That is how the yield return syntax works.

Comment: `yield return` can be used with methods that return *either* `IEnumerable<T>` *or* `IEnumerator<T>`. It’s only in the `foreach` loop where `IEnumerator<T>` can’t be used.

Answer (score 10):

Just to clarify

```
private static IEnumerator<TextBox> FindTextBoxes(Control rootControl)
```

Changes to

```
private static IEnumerable<TextBox> FindTextBoxes(Control rootControl)
```

That should be all :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you return IEnumerator, it will be a different enumerator object each time call that method (acting as though you reset the enumerator on each iteration). If you return IEnumerable then a foreach can enumerate based on the method with the  yield statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Generic function that gets all child controls of a certain type, 
// returned in a List collection
private static List<T> GetChildTextBoxes<T>(Control ctrl) where T : Control{
    List<T> tbs = new List<T>();
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls) {
        // If c is of type T, add it to the collection
        if (c is T) { 
            tbs.Add((T)c);
        }
    }
    return tbs;
}

private static void SetChildTextBoxesHeight(Control ctrl, int height) {
    foreach (TextBox t in GetChildTextBoxes<TextBox>(ctrl)) {
        t.Height = height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are given an enumerator, and need to use it in a for-each loop, you could use the following to wrap it:

```
static public class enumerationHelper
{
    public class enumeratorHolder<T>
    {
        private T theEnumerator;
        public T GetEnumerator() { return theEnumerator; }
        public enumeratorHolder(T newEnumerator) { theEnumerator = newEnumerator;}
    }
    static enumeratorHolder<T> toEnumerable<T>(T theEnumerator) { return new enumeratorHolder<T>(theEnumerator); }
    private class IEnumeratorHolder<T>:IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private IEnumerator<T> theEnumerator;
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return theEnumerator; }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return theEnumerator; }
        public IEnumeratorHolder(IEnumerator<T> newEnumerator) { theEnumerator = newEnumerator; }
    }
    static IEnumerable<T> toEnumerable<T>(IEnumerator<T> theEnumerator) { return new IEnumeratorHolder<T>(theEnumerator); }
}
```

The `toEnumerable` method will accept anything that [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [vb](/questions/tagged/vb) would regard an acceptable return type from `GetEnumerator`, and return something that can be used in `foreach`.  If the parameter is an `IEnumerator<>` the response will be an `IEnumerable<T>`, though calling `GetEnumerator` on it once will likely yield bad results.